# SpriteKit: Black Screen after move from SKScene to UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I'm stuck on transitioning from an SKScene to a ViewController that I've added to the Main.storyboard. I know there are tons of the same question but nothing works for me.
I would be grateful if I get an answer, anyway.

My code to transition:

```
func presentNextVC() {
    let vc = UIViewController(nibName: "NextVC", bundle: nil) as UIViewController
    if let responder = self.view?.nextResponder() {
        let vc = responder as UIViewController
        vc.presentViewController(NextVC(), animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

This function will be called by a TouchedNode-event. When node is touched, I think it moves to the NextVC, but I only get a black screen.

// EDIT: The solution:

```
func presentNextVC() {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextVc") as UIViewController
    let currentViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    currentViewController.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming that your `nextResponder` (if one is returned) is a `UIViewController`.  Can you verify that's true?  ...maybe also take a look at what `NextVC()` returns?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Yes NextVC is a UIViewController.
NextVC() is just the class of NextVC.swift which is a Controller of the viewController in Storyboard

Comment: OK...what about `responder`?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Just to complete this. I got it:
Added the solution in my First post! ;)